# ExtJS Toolbar button highlite

Tags: extjs

Iam design menu in ExtJs using Ext.Toolbar,

```
var ToolBar = new Ext.Toolbar({
            id: 'ToolBar',
            renderTo: 'divtoolbar',
            items: [
                    { xtype: 'spacer', width: 50 },
                    { xtype: 'tbbutton', text: 'Home', handler: function () { window.location = '@Url.Content("~/Home/Home/")'; } },
                    { xtype: 'tbseparator' },
                    { xtype: 'tbbutton', text: 'Calendar', handler: function () { window.location = '@Url.Content("~/calendar/eventCalendar/")'; } },
                    { xtype: 'tbseparator' },
                    { xtype: 'tbbutton', text: 'Locations' }
]
```

............
how to change or highlite clicked tbbutton

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the `addClass` method available with the button. Create a CSS style for the visited button and call `addClass` method in handler. Here is an example:

```
  handler:  function(b,e) {
     this.addClass('className');
  }
```

But in your case, I see that you are navigating away from the page. In such cases you will have to store the visited buttons in a cookie or use HTML5 storage.

I wonder why you are making a multipage ExtJS application and not following the single page approach?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply,,,,,,,,, Could you please send me an example for singlepage approch.......Thanks

Comment: in single page approach, you don't navigate to a new page. Instead, you open a window, panel etc in the same page. Look at "Combination Examples" available with ExtJS examples.